# How to tell which local branch is tracking which remote branch in Git?

Tags: git

I would like to know if there's a way to tell which local branch is tracking which remote branch in Git.

I'm using one remote server, which is named "origin".

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong however isnt' it a remote branch that is named origin by default rather than the server??

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Using the example of my copy of Puppet checked out from the upstream Git repository on Github.com...

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git://github.com/reductivelabs/puppet.git
  Push  URL: git://github.com/reductivelabs/puppet.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    0.24.x                 tracked
    0.25.x                 tracked
    2.6.x                  tracked
    master                 tracked
    next                   tracked
    primordial-ooze        tracked
    reins-on-a-horse       tracked
    testing                tracked
    testing-17-march       tracked
    testing-18-march       tracked
    testing-2-april        tracked
    testing-2-april-midday tracked
    testing-20-march       tracked
    testing-21-march       tracked
    testing-24-march       tracked
    testing-26-march       tracked
    testing-29-march       tracked
    testing-31-march       tracked
    testing-5-april        tracked
    testing-9-april        tracked
    testing4268            tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Then if I were to execute the following:

```
$ git checkout -b local_2.6 -t origin/2.6.x 
Branch local_2.6 set up to track remote branch 2.6.x from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'local_2.6'
```

And finally re-run the `git remote show origin` command again I will then see the following down near the bottom:

```
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    local_2.6 merges with remote 2.6.x
    master    merges with remote master
```

Comment: So does this mean you can track all the remote branches in puppet although you have a few local branches. What's the many "tracked" signs mean you see in the result of the command? "tracked" by which local branch?

Comment: The remote branches are tracked in that if you do a `git fetch` or `git pull` updates to the remote branches will be tracked in your cloned repository. The local branches are just that, local branches of the remote branches and thus updates to the remote branches will be tracked and merged in when the appropriate command to do so is given. I explicitly include the '-t' option when making the local branch to ensure it tracks the branch from which it originated from. Remember a local branch can also track another local branch so doesn't have to be a remote branch.

Comment: @PJ: The term “track” has two distinct meanings in Git.

The “tracked” lines in `git remote show remote-name` refer to [“tracking branches”](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_tracking_branch) (snapshots of branches from remote repositories).

The “merges with” lines refer to local branches that have an [“upstream branch”](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_upstream_branch) configuration (made with with the `--track`/`-t` option of *git branch* or *git checkout* and thus often confused with “tracking branches”).

Comment: "[remote-tracking branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_remote_tracking_branch)" is the up-to-date glossary entry for "tracking branches" mentioned above. The doc was updated in [8b3f3f84](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/Documentation/glossary-content.txt?id=8b3f3f84b27e6bbac1b1558166b44431a8e78bb1).

Answer (score 132):

For all branches:

```
git branch -avv
```

For local branches only:

```
git branch -lvv
```

For remote branches only:

```
git branch -rvv
```

shows you all branches as well as the name of the upstream branch.

Comment: This is by far the simplest and fullest answer!

Comment: On git version 1.7.7.5 this is showing me the local branch and the sha-1 it points to, but it doesn't show the tracked remote branch...

Comment: Works for me on git version 1.7.4.1

The second 'v' is required to show the remote tracking branch.

Comment: to reduce output `git branch -lvv` show just local branches with upstream might be useful

Comment: ^`git branch -vv` works for me...

Comment: @Mike & Peter, 1.8 doesn't show the correspondence to remote branches for me either, but git -lvv does (and does it more concisely).

Comment: @Mike I thought I had the same problem, but it was because my tracking wasn't set up right. Once I setup the tracking properly, then -avv -vv -lvv all work. To setup tracking, do `git branch -u origin/master`

Comment: I'm new to git. Can you tell me where is documentation for this options? I don't see it [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) and [here](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html)

Comment: @CichyK24 you can see the full list of options to all the git commands in the man pages - type "man git branch" in a terminal. The man pages can also be seen online here for instance: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Comment: This is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 52):

Jeremy Bouse illustrates [how `git remote show` displays tracking information](https://serverfault.com/questions/175052/how-to-tell-which-local-branch-is-tracking-which-remote-branch-in-git/175077#175077). That should be sufficient if you only want the information for human consumption.

If you plan on using the information in an automated context (e.g. a script) you should use the lower-level (“plumbing”) [`git for-each-ref`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html) instead.

```
% git remote show origin
* remote origin
⋮
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
    pu     merges with remote pu
⋮
% git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) <- %(upstream:short)' refs/heads
master <- origin/master
pu <- origin/pu
```

The `git for-each-ref` learned the `%(upstream)` token in [Git 1.6.3](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.6.3.txt). With earlier versions of Git you will have to extract the tracking information with `git config branch.<name>.remote` and `git config branch.<name>.merge` (probably using `git for-each-ref` to build the commands for each local branch name).

Comment: Your answers output is much more succinct and easier to follow, so you get the up vote :)

Comment: To make it less succinct, but provide a nice way to visually check that remote names are the same as the local branch names, a common git gotcha: in bash `git for-each-ref --format=$'\n'' '' '' '' '' '' ''/%(refname:short);%(upstream:short)' refs/heads | tr ';' $'\n'`

Answer (score 20):

For a particular branch, you can use `git rev-parse` with the `@{u}` or `@{upstream}` suffix on the branch name, e.g.:

```
$  git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
refs/remotes/github-mhl/master
```

... or for the abbreviated form, add `--abbrev-ref`

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
github-mhl/master
```

You can generally use the `branch@{upstream}` syntax wherever a commit is expected.

Comment: +1 Your answer gave me exactly what I needed: `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD` vs. `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD@{u}`, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I use the following shell script (named `git-tracks`) to show the remote branch that is tracked by the current branch:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)
branch=${branch##refs/heads/}
remote=$(git config "branch.${branch}.remote")
remoteBranch=$(git config "branch.${branch}.merge")
remoteBranch=${remoteBranch##refs/heads/}

echo "${remote:?}/${remoteBranch:?}"
```

This could also use the mentioned `git for-each-ref`, but I found the direct access somewhat simpler than filtering the output for the current branch.

Comment: You might consider using "set -e" at the top of the script. That will allow you to remove all of the instances of "|| exit $?" while retaining the same fail-early behavior.

Comment: @JohnWhitley: Thanks, I've edited my answer. I know about `set -e`, but usually stick to the explicit checking. But in this case, it's really better.

Comment: Not working for me on `git version 1.9.4`. Echos nothing :(

Answer (score 10):

`.git/config` file also will provide the tracking branch info as

```
[remote "Hub"]
    url = ssh://xxxx/tmp/Hub
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/Hub/*
[branch "develop"]
    remote = Hub
    merge = refs/heads/develop
[branch "Dev1"]
    remote = Test
    merge = refs/heads/Dev1
[remote "Test"]
    url = ssh://xxxx/tmp/gittesting/Dev1GIT
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/Test/*
```

Comment: This (I think) answers the question: "What URL is being used for the tracking branch of branch X?"  We have branch Dev1 with remote Test, and remote Test with a URL.  It doesn't explicitly say "tracking", but that seems to be what it shows.  It's common practice to rename and add "origin" when the upstream host changes (move from github to gitlab, say), but that leaves the tracking information and reporting stale.

Answer (score 7):

```
git branch -vv
```

shows exactly what you ask for. It shows the local branches together with the corresponding remote branch they are tracking.

Answer (score 2):

Add these runes to the `[alias]` section of your .gitconfig file:

```
show-tracking = !sh -c 'git ls-remote . |grep `git log -1 --grep="git-svn-id" --format=%H`|perl -pe "s/[[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]//"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find the corresponding remote branch (if any) for each local branch within a loop that was acting on a list of the local branches.  I ended up using the following:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short):%(upstream:short)' refs/heads | grep "^LocalBranchName:.*/" | sed "s/^LocalBranchName://"
```

This will output nothing (an empty string) for local branches that don't have a corresponding remote branch ("someremote/somebranch").

Answer (score -1):

Try `git branch` [with options](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-branch):

```
 -r
List or delete (if used with -d) the remote-tracking branches. 

-a
List both remote-tracking branches and local branches.
```

Otherwise, examine your `.git/config`.

Comment: They show branches, but I don't understand which one is tracking which.

Comment: Exactly as PJ said, you have to do git branch -vv to get the connection between the local and remote branches.